# How to initialize object by adding property to inherited class

Tags: c#, linq, inheritance

Is there a way of easily declaring an object that's extension of another object by using the inherited object in the declaration in C# using Linq? The example below is something like what I want to happen. I'm trying to avoid rewriting all the properties of the superclass.

Example:

```
public class Thing {
    public int Property {get; set;}
}

public class AnotherThing : Thing {
    public string AnotherProperty {get;set;}
}

public class Main {
    public List<AnotherThing> GetAnotherThings() =>
        GetListOfThings().Select(t => new AnotherThing(t) 
            { AnotherProperty = "Hello" }
        ).ToList();

    public List<Thing> GetListOfThings() {...}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set those properties somewhere in your code at last; in your linq query or in constructor.
As an option `AnotherThing` can be this way:

```
public class AnotherThing : Thing 
{
    AnotherThing (Thing value)
    {
        this.Property = value.Property;
    }
    public string AnotherProperty {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, man. This is the best solution. It at least moves the bulkiness out of sight.

Answer (score 0):

You need to Write a constructor on `AnotherThing` that takes a `Thing` and sets up the new object based on the . There's no shortcut I'm afraid.

```
public AnotherThing (Thing thing)
{
    this.Property = value.Property;
    // i would be careful to either make this a deep copy,
       //or have a DeepClone() method on Thing
}
```

If there are private fields you can't dig out from that constructor, it may be a good idea to create a method on `Thing` that returns a [Memento object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_pattern). I would recommend against having a method in `Thing` that returns `AnotherThing`.

Edit:

Are you trying to create a `Thing` in order to create `AnotherThing`, would calling the `Thing` constructor from the `AnotherThing` better suit your needs? : `public AnotherThing (int foo) : base(foo){}`

Comment: In my scenario, the thing is discarded immediately. What kinds of things could happen if I don't deep copy?

Comment: Shouldn't matter in that case, just in general. The reference resources owned by both objects would be the same. What is your scenario?

Comment: Thing is an Entity Framework entity and AnotherThing is a class that adds a couple properties to it (some are computed, some are pulled from somewhere else, etc). I have this scenario about 20 times, so the extra bulkiness is annoying to look at.